# Preventing Amazon S3 Bandwidth Stealing?

Tags: security, amazon-s3, storage, bandwidth

I have a Image Hosting Site that is using Amazon S3 as a main source for bandwith and storage.

I have a few option here to prevent other sources from stealing my bandwith, but I am hoping there are more or other alternatives.

1. Query String Authentication
2. [Url Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570890/amazon-s3-url-rewrite)

Are there better ways to prevent thieves from hot-linking to my Amazon S3 files and using it on their site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to prevent hot linking is to use new 
Amazon S3 bucket policy feature. See our blog post on the example of such a policy

http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2010/07/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-of-your.html

Comment: if you use a IP's as a referrer policy will it DNS query domains against IP? I am thinking of a scenario where you may have many domains and it would be easier to list server IP's.